# QTableWidget::item() QTableWidget::cellWidget ()?

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget, qtablewidget

Does anyone know the relation between return value of

```
QTableWidget::item(x, y)
```

and

```
 QTableWidget::cellWidget (x, y)
```

in the same QTableWidget and same row.column.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all in the return value.

`item()` returns the `QTableWidgetItem*` associated with that row/column.

`cellWidget()` is more closely associated with `setItemWidget(QWidget*)`, and returns the `QWidget*` that was given in the `setItemWidget` call.